# updatedTransactions(transactionState == .restored) vs paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, swift5

As the title describes, what is the actual different?

If I have this:

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {

            } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {

            } else if transaction.transactionState == .restored { // <- This one
        }
    }
```

Do I still need to use this (if yes, what code to use here, and what code in `transactionState == .restored`?:

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you start restoring transactions, any available transactions are presented to your payment queue observer with the `.restored` state.  At this point you should restore the transaction; effectively processing it in the same way that you processed the initial purchase.

Depending on what transactions are available to be restored, you will get from 0 to n transactions presented (There may not be any transactions available for restoration).

Once all available transactions have been presented, you will get a call to `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`.  You will always get 1 call to this method for each time you call `restoreCompletedTransactions`.

Note that no details of the restored transactions are passed to this method. The purpose of this method is to allow you to perform any final housekeeping such as updating your UI.

For example, you could display a "Restoring" message when the user taps your restore button and hide that message when you get the call to `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`

Comment: Ok, I see! But how come, when the user has already bought the IAP, and press the purchase button again, the `transactionState == .restored` does not run at all. But when tapping the restore button, the `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` runs. Why does not the `transactionState == .restored` run tho, when pressing the purchase button?

Comment: Because in the first case you didn't initiate a restore, you initiated a purchase.  If it is a non-consumable purchase then the user wasn't charged for the second purchase