# How to deal with multiple In-App Purchases in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have two In-App Purchases in my iOS app and unable to manage more than one productID correctly. Right now the code only restores the first of my IAPs, and does not unlock the second one after purchased or restored.

The problem might be with the if/if else statements in the .purchased or in the paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished() part.

I'm completely hopeless as **no YouTube tutorial, wiki page or documentation deals with two IAPs, they only focus on one. I would be also happy if someone can just drop me an example code snippet dealing with to IAPs.**

```
//MARK: Purchase buttons

@IBAction func didTapBuyPRODUCT1(_ sender: Any) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
        paymentRequest.productIdentifier = "example.productID1"
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
    } else {
    }
}

@IBAction func didTapBuyPRODUCT2(_ sender: Any) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
        let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
        paymentRequest.productIdentifier = "example.productID2"
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
    } else {
    }
 }
    
    
//MARK: paymentQueue()

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
            
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            
            if prodID == "example.productID1" {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product1purchased") }
            if prodID == "example.productID2" {
                UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product2purchased")
            }
            
            purchaseUIFeedback()

            SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            
        } else if transaction.transactionState == .restored {
            
        } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
            print("Transaction failed")
        } else if transaction.transactionState == .purchasing {
            print("Purchasing")
        } else if transaction.transactionState == .deferred {
            print("Deferred!")
        }
    }
}

//MARK: Restore Button

    @IBAction func restoreButton(_ sender: Any) {
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    
}

//MARK:restoreFunc()
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        if prodID == "example.productID1" {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product1purchased")}
        if prodID == "example.productID2" {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product2purchased") }
    }
    purchaseUIFeedback()
}


//MARK: UI FEEDBACK

@IBOutlet weak var product1BuyButton: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var product1Image: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var product2BuyButton: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var product2Image: UIButton!


func purchaseUIFeedback() {
    if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "product1purchased") != nil) == true {
        product1Image.image = UIImage(named: "Product 1 In-App Purchase Logo PURCHASED")
        product1BuyButton.isEnabled = false
        product1BuyButton.setTitle("Purchased", for: .normal)
    } else {
        product1Image.image = UIImage(named: "Product 1  In-App Purchase NOT PURCHASED")
        product1BuyButton.isEnabled = true }
    
    if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "product2purchased") != nil) == true {
        product2Image.image = UIImage(named: "Product 2  In-App Purchase PURCHASED")
        product2BuyButton.isEnabled = false
        product2BuyButton.setTitle("Purchased", for: .normal)
    } else {
        product2Image.image = UIImage(named: "Product 2  In-App Purchase NOT PURCHASED")
        product2BuyButton.isEnabled = true }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, your `updatedTransactions` code is completely wrong. You are failing to call `finishTransaction` in the `restored` or `failed` case.

Comment: I've fixed it but unfortunately it still does not solve my problem. Even now only the 1st product is restored.

Comment: `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is not the correct place to process restored purchases. It is the correct place to update your UI to reflect that restoration is complete. Restored transactions are presented to the `updatedTransactions` handler and we can see that your code does nothing in the `.restored` case; that is your problem.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60959941/updatedtransactionstransactionstate-restored-vs-paymentqueuerestorecomplet/60960213#60960213)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have also mistyped one of my product IDs, but I've solved it by experimenting with loops and if statements. Anyone who founds this in their search results looking for a solution to implement multiple In-App Purchases in a simple way, here is my code in Swift:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit
        
class settingsViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
            
        let productID1 = "example.productID1"
        let productID2 = "example.productID2"
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        
        //MARK: Purchase buttons
        
        @IBAction func didTapBuy1(_ sender: Any) {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
                let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
                paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID1
                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
            } else {
              }
        }
        
        @IBAction func didTapBuy2(_ sender: Any) {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
                let paymentRequest = SKMutablePayment()
                paymentRequest.productIdentifier = productID2
                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(paymentRequest)
            } else {
            }
        }
        
        
        func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
            for transaction in transactions {
                if transaction.transactionState == .purchased {
                        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
                        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
                        if prodID == "example.productID1" {
                            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product1purchased")
                        }
                        if prodID == "example.productID2" {
                            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product2purchased")
                        }
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    
                    //MARK: .restored
                } else if transaction.transactionState == .restored {
                        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
                        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
                        if prodID == "example.productID1" {
                            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product1purchased")
                        }
                        if prodID == "example.productID2" {
                            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "product2purchased")
                        }
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                    
                } else if transaction.transactionState == .failed {
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
                
                } else if transaction.transactionState == .purchasing {
                    
                } else if transaction.transactionState == .deferred {

                }
            }
        }
        
        //MARK: Restore Button
        @IBAction func restoreButton(_ sender: Any) {
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
        
        func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
            //UI updater func() is here
        }
    }
```